# Centering Divs with responsive browser

Tags: html, css

As Illustrated in the next graphic I have a problem with my responsive code: I have 3 sections called square1, 2 and 3 with a white div inside. text on top of it and an icon with an absolute position. Everything fine from 920px to higher browsing. Now, from 720 to 940 pixels I'm trying to give this 3 elements a 50% of width, to display two on top and 1 at the bottom, but centered. so far is a mess. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? my actual     [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ombpqhjh/)

HTML:

```
<div id="section2">

        <div id="centralize2">
            <div id="square1">
                <div id="white1">
                    <img src="images/hexagon1.png" class="hexagon" />
                    <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur1</h2>
                    <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="square2">
                <div id="white1">
                    <img src="images/hexagon2.png" class="hexagon" />
                    <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur2</h2>
                    <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="square3">

                <div id="white1">
                    <img src="images/hexagon3.png" class="hexagon" />
                    <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur3</h2>
                    <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks!!

[image: browser problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to achieve what you want. Don't use absolute positioning if it's not necessary. If the width is bigger than `940px`, the divs will display next to each other. Try it out in the full version of the code snippet.

Also cleaned up some code, as you can't have multiple divs with the same `id`. That's not valid markup. Use a `class` instead.

```css
#section2 {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #112e4c;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#square1, #square2, #square3 {
 margin-top: 59px;
}

.white1 {
  margin: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

.hexagon {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
}

.title1 {
 font-size:18px;
 margin-top: 90px;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 color: #112e4c;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.description2 {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 16px;
 margin-top:20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #8da0b4;
 
}

@media all and (min-width:720px) {
  
  #centralize2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }

  #square1, #square2, #square3 {
   flex-basis: calc(50%);
  }
  
}


@media all and (min-width:940px) {
  
  #square1, #square2, #square3 {
   flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="section2">
  
   
      <div id="centralize2">
    <div id="square1">
     <div class="white1">
      <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur1</h2>
      <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="square2">
     <div class="white1">
      <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur2</h2>
      <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <div id="square3">
     
     <div class="white1">
      <h2 class="title1">Ipsum Dolor Consectetur3</h2>
      <h3 class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a dolor ac sapien semper maximus vel vel arcu. Praesent venenatis semper ornare. Donec blandit feugiat tellus. </h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks @roy but what I'm trying to achieve is to avoid that large windows or squares from 940 to smaller screens, there's a space between 720 and 940px that I want to show them with 50% of width each one, not 100%, I'll use the 100% only from 720px to smaller screens, like in the fiddle I've prepared:)

Comment: @Eugenio I updated the code to your needs: displaying two in a row between `720px` and `940px` and above that 3 items.

Comment: Wow @roy you're awesome men!! ok I'll read carefully what you've coded to understand it better! thanks!!

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, I'm here to help you.

Comment: Hi there @roy, just to test, I've inserted your code exactly as it is now in a new html file with an internal css call. but I can see that screen larger than 920px is showing each title or white box with 100% of width and not divided space in 3 areas like in your example code here:( why could be that? thanks!

Comment: That's weird. What does the developer toolbar say? What browser are you using?

Comment: thanks pal, I solved that, just some minor problems with my code:) working fine now, another question, the flex is taking all the width of the browser but what if I want to give it a specific width to work with? let's say 80%?

Comment: Last thing: you could set a `width: 80%;` on `#centralize2` to achieve this. The content inside will try to fit into this space.

Comment: Hey @Roy I did and works, the thing is that is moving it all to the left instead of keeping the area (80%) at the center :( I'm not that familiarized with the flex mode

Comment: Setting a `margin: 0 auto;` and `width: 80%;` on `#centralize2` will do.

Answer (score -2):

It has to do with your absolute positioning. Try removing the absolute positioning, and try floating the blocks left and add your margins as needed. Will try and get a working demo together for you asap, at work atm.

Got a chance to try and edit your demo, I believe you're looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ah5zz8qq/

```css
#section2 {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #112e4c;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#centralize2 {
  width: 880px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#square1 {
  display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
}

#square2 {
  display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 position: relative;
}

#square3 {
  display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
}

#white1 {
 width: 280px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.hexagon {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
  top: 0;
 margin-left: -52px;
 margin-top: -59px;
}

.title1 {
  display: block;
 font-size:18px;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 color: #112e4c;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.description2 {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 16px;
 margin-top:20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #8da0b4;
}


@media all and (max-width:940px) {
  
#centralize2 {
 width: 90%;
} 

#section2 {
 height: 720px;
}

#square1 {
  display: block;
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

#square2 {
  display: block;
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#square3 {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
 width: 50%;
 float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#white1 {
 width:300px;
}



}

@media all and (max-width:720px) {
  
#section2 {
 height: 1070px;
}

#buttons {
 margin-top:25px;
}

#square1 {
 width: 100%;
}

#square2 {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top:340px;
}

#square3 {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top:340px;
}

#white1 {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 
} 
}
}
```

Comment: @Eugenio updated my comment and added a fork of your demo. Let me know if this is what you were looking for and if it works for you or if you need any additional help with it.